# What is ANT_HOME

Tags: linux, middleware

Can someone please explain, What is `ANT_HOME`?

Like in our environment it's set

`-bash-3.2$ echo $ANT_HOME 
/mhfidm01/apps/oracle/middleware/modules/org.apache.ant.patch_1.2.0.0_1-7-1.jar`

Comment: ANT_HOME is environment path variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's the location of where [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) is installed.

Its value should be a directory path, not a JAR file.

From [the Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#setup):

> Set the `ANT_HOME` environment variable to the directory where you installed Ant. On some operating systems, Ant's startup scripts can guess `ANT_HOME` (Unix dialects and Windows NT/2000), but it is better to not rely on this behavior.